# Importing source files into test file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, python-3.7

I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
│   
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_one.py
```

I want to import app.main in test_one. I went through similar stackoverflow questions and tried to add the path to the app folder in the test_one.py file as follows:

```
sys.path.append('/path to project/app')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

How can I import the files from app into the test_one.py file? Is there a simple `from ... import` statement to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what unit testing framework you are using, but if you are using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), it already supports that kind of app/test organization where [the tests are outside the application code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code).

> ```
> setup.py
> mypkg/
>     __init__.py
>     app.py
>     view.py
> tests/
>     test_app.py
>     test_view.py
>     ...
> ```
>
> - ..
> - If you don’t have a `setup.py` file and are relying on the fact that
>     Python by default puts the current directory in `sys.path` to import
>     your package, you can execute `python -m pytest` to execute the tests
>     against the local copy directly, without using `pip`.

Your codes are already structured correctly. You don't need to manually set `sys.path`. You can use `from app import main` normally (see my sample *test_one.py* below). The only thing I would add is a **pytest.ini** to specify the test paths and the pattern for the test files.

**directory structure**:

```
Project
├── pytest.ini
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
│   
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_one.py
```

**pytest.ini**:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -v
console_output_style = count
python_files = test_*.py
testpaths = tests
```

sample **main.py**:

```
def calculate(x, y):
    return x + y
```

sample **test_one.py**:

```
from app import main

def test_calculate():
    assert(3 == main.calculate(1, 2))
```

running pytest:

```
$ pytest tests
=============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.6.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /home/gino/.virtualenvs/test-py37/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/gino/Project, inifile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                  

tests/test_one.py::test_calculate PASSED                                                                                                                                     [1/1]

============================================================================ 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================================================================
```